# create groups in cube portfolio

Tags: html, css

On the same page I have different portfolios, so I want to keep them separated. Now when I'm clicking on a pic and it shows as lightbox, at the end of a serie the cubeportfolio takes me to the next serie, but I'd want it to go back to the first pic of the same serie.
With the previous lightbox I added rel='group1', and so it worked. But with the Cubeportfolio lightbox it seems to be different. Any help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, sorry.
Just added this:

```
 data-cbp-lightbox="group"
```